# How to count the number of entries belonging to each group?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my data frame:

```
df = 

GROUP    GRADE   TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME    TOTAL_WAIT_TIME
AAA      1       45                    20
AAA      4       40                    23
AAA      5       35                    21
BBB      2       30                    24
BBB      3       55                    22
```

I want to group entries by `GROU` and `GRADE`, estimate mean `TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME` and mean `TOTAL_WAIT_TIME` for each grouping, as well as count the number of entries belonging to each group.

I don't know how to perform counting:

```
output = df.groupby(['GROUP','GRADE'])
           .agg({'TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME' : 'mean', 'TOTAL_WAIT_TIME' : 'mean'})
           .value_counts()
           .reset_index()
```

I also tried to add `, 'COUNT' : 'count'`, but the column `COUNT` should already exist.

Comment: `df.groupby(['GROUP','GRADE']).agg({'TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME' : ['mean', 'count'], 'TOTAL_WAIT_TIME' : ['mean', 'count']})` - add count to agg?

Comment: @JohnGalt: Thanks, but it creates two identical sub-columns. I need the one called  as `COUNT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, and the documentation is light on `agg`:

```
df.groupby(['GROUP','GRADE']).agg({'TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME' : 'mean',
                                   'TOTAL_WAIT_TIME' : ['mean', 'count']})
Out[45]: 
            TOTAL_WAIT_TIME       TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME
                       mean count               mean
GROUP GRADE                                         
AAA   1                  20     1                 45
      4                  23     1                 40
      5                  21     1                 35
BBB   2                  24     1                 30
      3                  22     1                 55
```

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to put `count` into a separate column called `COUNT`, not as a sub-column of `TOTAL_WAIT_TIME`?

Comment: I mean that counting should be done at the level of `GROUP` and `GRADE` without caring about `TOTAL_WAIT_TIME`.

Comment: That's exactly what's doing: counting doesn't impact from which column you're processing it for a given grouping as it doesn't depend on the content of the column. I picked up one of them by convention, you can pick up the other one if you want: it doesn't matter and gives you the expected count. As per the level, you can easily reindex your column to get one level only

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to extend [this great @Boud's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41961958/5741205) with another example, where you can give custom column names:

```
In [57]: funcs = {
    ...:   'TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME': {'mean_service':'mean', 'count_service':'size'},
    ...:   'TOTAL_WAIT_TIME' : {'mean_wait':'mean', 'count_wait':'size'}
    ...: }
    ...:

In [58]: df
Out[58]:
  GROUP  GRADE  TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME  TOTAL_WAIT_TIME
0   AAA      1                  45               20
1   AAA      1                 100              100
2   AAA      4                  40               23
3   AAA      5                  35               21
4   BBB      2                  30               24
5   BBB      3                  55               22

In [59]: df.groupby(['GROUP','GRADE']).agg(funcs)
Out[59]:
            TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME               TOTAL_WAIT_TIME
                  mean_service count_service      count_wait mean_wait
GROUP GRADE
AAA   1                   72.5             2               2        60
      4                   40.0             1               1        23
      5                   35.0             1               1        21
BBB   2                   30.0             1               1        24
      3                   55.0             1               1        22
```

now you can drop the column level:

```
x = df.groupby(['GROUP','GRADE']).agg(funcs)
x.columns = x.columns.droplevel(0)


In [63]: x
Out[63]:
             mean_service  count_service  count_wait  mean_wait
GROUP GRADE
AAA   1              72.5              2           2         60
      4              40.0              1           1         23
      5              35.0              1           1         21
BBB   2              30.0              1           1         24
      3              55.0              1           1         22

In [64]: x.reset_index()
Out[64]:
  GROUP  GRADE  mean_service  count_service  count_wait  mean_wait
0   AAA      1          72.5              2           2         60
1   AAA      4          40.0              1           1         23
2   AAA      5          35.0              1           1         21
3   BBB      2          30.0              1           1         24
4   BBB      3          55.0              1           1         22
```

Comment: Thanks. `COUNT` should count the number of rows belonging  to each combination of `GROUP`  and `GRADE`, but in this solution `GROUP`, `GRADE`,`TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME` and `TOTAL_WAIT_TIME` are used.

Comment: @Dinosaurius, you have provided a data set where all groups have only one element, that's why i've added one row with `TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME  =100, TOTAL_WAIT_TIME=100`

Comment: @Dinosaurius, can you post the output of `print(x.columns)` __before__ dropping?

Comment: I have resolved this issue. The problem was that I called `reset_index()` before and after dropping.